# RelativeLayout: button pushes other button off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-relativelayout

I am trying to get three buttons next to each other, the left one and right one are small ones, the middle one should fill up the rest of the width - 2x2dp (=margin).
I coded the following, but it keeps pushing my right button off screen, any ideas on how to solve this? There might be a way to privilige the left one and right one?

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bPreviousQuestion"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:background="#c8c8c8"
                android:text="&lt;"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bBack"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bPreviousQuestion"
                android:background="#c8c8c8"
                android:text="Go Back"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bNextQuestion"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bBack"
                android:background="#c8c8c8"
                android:text="&gt;"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bNextQuestion"
```

to your "back" Button. In "next" remove this line:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bBack"
```

And add:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: Nice one Sam, thanks! So you can indeed somehow privilege the buttons by making them depending on the other ones which you 'fix' on screen, thanks man!

Comment: Yes, through trial and error you'll discover which attributes take precedence over others. For example, `layout_alignParent____` is a more definitive attribute that fixes a View to a location, while `toLeftOf` and `toRightOf` are dynamic by design. You'll also discover that attributes like `layout_center_____` don't budge, they will _always_ be centered on their particular axis...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Set {Previous} to aligned parent left with 42dp width.

Set {Next} to aligned parent right with 42dp width.

Set {Back} to be to the right of Prev, and to the Left of Next with fill_parent width.

This *should* fill between the buttons with the back button if I undersand the layout correctly.

Answer (score 1):

use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPreviousQuestion"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="#c8c8c8"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBack"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c8c8c8"
        android:text="Go Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNextQuestion"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="#c8c8c8"
        android:text=">"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need the relative layout to put it at the bottom... :)

Comment: `LinearLayout` can be put at bottom!

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd button's layout_width is "fill_parent"

Comment: Yes i know, and that is pushing it off, but can I somehow  privilege the left and right one against the middle button? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

for your second button that is middle button, you are using  android:layout_width="fill_parent". Instead of that use android:layout_width="42dp", then you will see your third one

Comment: Yes, however depending on the size of the screen, the buttons will look weird. The OP, if understood correctly, would like to see the back button stretched to fill the between space of the Prev and Next buttons.

Comment: Correct Matt, that is what I need to accomplish

Comment: then you need to use linear layout inside relative layout for placing in bottom. In linear layout set layout:weight for all the three button